# PSpice Bipolar Junction Transistors Modeling

Tags: transistors, rf, modeling, pspice, bipolar

i want to simulate the circuit AmpopTBH2, on PSpice.
On image 1hbt.png [image]we can see that Draft4 is working fine, on image 2hbt_pardif.png [image]is the same circuit as Draft4 but on PSpice that circuit won't work right, because on Green voltage marker the same point as vpardif on LTspice, the voltage is always 3V (3vpardif_pspice.png)[image]
The transistor i am using is BFR92A/PLP, because on PHILRF.lib the BFR92 is not there, no model available, but BFR92A is still the complementary of BFT92 so i thought it would work on PSpice, but unfortunately yet no.

The only circuit of HBT on PSpice is working right now for me is Class B Amplifier: HBTclassB.png[image] & HBTclassB_vout_graph.png .[image]

I also checked the SIEMENS.lib, but i didn't find any PNP/NPN complementary transistors, i have to use both types. I need a Transition Frequency about 5GHz.

I have physically (brought) the transistors  BFR92 and BFT92.

Edit: My question is what reason might be that the Differential Amplifier work well on LTSpice but on PSpice not ?
(On PSpice the voltage on nodes is always 3 Volts, and the current on this nodes is in the range of 1 pico Ampere pA, and it should be in the range of micro Ampere uA).

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, it is unclear what question you want answered, this is a Q&A site: you provide the question, we answer it.

Comment: Hi, sorry, yeah you are right, i forgot to ask a question, i edited my post already. Basicaly my question is what reason might be that the Differential Amplifier work well on LTSpice but on PSpice not ?